# Is Google PageRank distributed differently to external and internal links?

Tags: seo, google, pagerank

Google has been internally using PageRank for a long time, so if I have two links in one paragraph, one is my an internal link to my website, and the second is an external link, does Google pass the same PageRank to both links?

Comment: Why are you asking?   What would you do differently if PageRank is passed equally or not?  Google is very tight lipped about how their algorithms actually work now.  It is very hard to answer your question definitively, but we can help you make decisions about your options based on our experience.

Answer (score 2):

Pagerank... is so the 90's. Google algorithm has come along way and pagerank no longer works the same as it once did. Its now one factor of over two hundred and is a minor factor, not a major factor like it used to be.

But to answer your question people have always believed that juice flows evenly  and equally across internal and externally links on the page. Nofollow can be used on external links should you want to retain that juice. But I must express... PageRank is meaningless and you are best to focus your efforts on quality, diversity and relevance.

I recommend that you read some SEO guides written in the last couple of years, ideally the type of ones that do not even mention pagerank.

Comment: Pagerank is still important. If it is not, then Google penguin algorithm will not roll out to penalize sites who made bad backlinks. Why Google penalize them? why Google force user to use [nofollow tag on widget links](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-reminder-about-widget-links.html)? There is nofollow attribute because of Pagerank. Whenever you read official document about nofollow tag, you will see they clearly said that nofollow link does not pass pagerank, and use it for affliate links or bad links, so Google don't count them in PR calculation. PR is important as always.

Comment: I have analysis PR article in wikipedia and read same page via old web archive machine, but it does not say clearly how they pass PR to outbound links. I know that PR is kept to each webpages but didn't find any patent or official web docs on how they treat them.

Comment: Your mistaken. Penguin does not roll out slaps based on PR. It works on diversity, trust but most of all relevancy. Having 10,000 links from pagerank 7 sites about 'CARS' linking to a site about dogs will give you a vip membership to club penguin. I never implied that PR is not a factor, its merely a factor. You will find viewing articles like 10 years old to mention about how pagerank flows, at the time it was lead to believe that pagerank flowed evenly. I stand firm with what I said, PageRank is not the same as it once was and its a 'minor' factor.

Comment: I am not saying penguin only slap site based on PR, They clearly said, that, if any website will try to manipulate our Pagerank algorithm, we will penalize them. Google using 200+ signals, and all of the signals have different weight, and as per my think PR have higher weight among others.

Answer (score 1):

To support what Simon is saying, Google PageRank is not what you think it is nor is it as powerful as you think it is.

Links are important. High quality links are always gold. Make no mistake about that.

The PageRank calculation is now achieved using a proximity method that mirrors network trust models rather than being recursive. Essentially, the results are the same, however, if a new page appears, a PageRank for the page can be immediately applied instead of waiting. For the recursive calculation to work, all PageRank for all pages must be calculated over and over again (the recursive part) until the calculated difference is within a statistical range where the effect is essentially 0. This was run only quarterly originally, then less, and then adjusted to run more often. The recursive method ironically is fairly fast, but not efficient overall. Whereas the network trust proximity method is immediate and can be applied to just one page or as many as needed anytime.

PageRank is **NOT** what people think it is. A PR6 page with two links does not pass PR3 through each link. It is not that simple. Each site/page can have an authority cap applied. For example, PR6 is likely reduced when applying the PageRank calculations whereas PR1 will not be. As well, link quality is calculated based upon quite a few criteria and a value between 0 and .9 applied. So that PR6 with two links is passing much less than PR3 based upon the PR cap value and the link value which is less than 1. The reason for this is to apply a more natural curve to the PageRank calculation so that new pages can compete against super authorities. Otherwise, the PageRank algorithm can never work.

Lastly, consider that PageRank is not the sole pivotal metric. It never really was, however, with more metrics in play these days, it's importance has diminished quite a lot as it should. I want you to think in two parts. One is on the index side, and the other is on the query side. PageRank is applied to the index as many metrics are, however, many metrics are applied on the query side. For example, PageRank is calculated and applied within the index, and page relevance to the query is applied on the query side. Page relevance can easily override PageRank so that a page with a lower PR score can actually perform better for a particular query because it is more relevant.

Now to your question. Is the PR calculation applied to internal links different from all inbound and outbound links? (I cleaned it up a bit to make my point.) The answer is Yes. However, only in this regard. The PR model for all links in and out of a site starts with super authorities, those sites that rank extremely high such as Wikipedia, and is calculated from that starting point to include all links to and from any page as inbound and outbound links but not internal links. As for the PR calculation for internal links, they start at the home page and are limited to that site only not to include inbound or outbound links. Other than that, the PR caclutaions are the same. Clear? In otherwords, PR applied globally (across the whole web) is applied through a site whereas PR applied only to one site (internally) remains within the site.

Answer (score 0):

No Google doesn't pass any page rank for both the links it completely depends on the DA of the website.

When you're giving internal link within your website...it has to be relevant and both the pages will perform well on Google. So, be careful when you're implementing internal & external links on the website.